# Como poderia melhor desempenho de um SELECT com vários INNER JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-select

Tenho um `SELECT` com vários `INNER JOIN` e algumas funções como `replace`, `if`..

Esse `SELECT` pega todas informações que eu preciso, mas demora muito.

Existe alguma forma de otimizar esse `SELECT`?

```
SELECT
as_assinaturas.id, 
as

_clientes.id, 
as_clientes.nome, 
as_clientes.email, 

CONCAT(as_enderecos.endereco, as_enderecos.complemento), 

as_enderecos.bairro,
as_enderecos.cidade, 
as_estados.sigla, 
as_enderecos.cep, "Brasil" AS "País", 

as_clientes.telefone, 
as_assinaturas.ed_inicial,
(as_campanhas.edicoes + as_assinaturas.ed_inicial + as_assinaturas.ed_ajuste_imp) - 1,
as_produtos.titulo, 
as_campanhas.edicoes,
as_tipo_assinaturas.nome, 

REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(as_assinaturas.status, 'I', 'Inativo'), 'A', 'Ativo'), 'C', 'Cancelado'), 'B', 'Bloqueado') AS "STATUS", 
as_assinaturas.status,
as_assinaturas.created,
as_pagamentos.valor,
as_pagamentos.data_pagamento, 
as_ordens.tipo_de_pagamento, 
IF(as_campanhas.nome LIKE('%Migra%'),'content','digisa') AS "OBSERVACAO", 
as_ordens.contrato,
as_assinaturas.vendedor, 
as_campanhas.distribuicao, 
as_assinaturas.id AS "ID LEGADO", 
as_representantes.nome 

FROM as_clientes 

INNER JOIN as_assinaturas ON as_clientes.id = as_assinaturas.cliente_id 
INNER JOIN as_enderecos ON as_enderecos.cliente_id = as_clientes.id 
INNER JOIN as_estados ON as_enderecos.estado_id = as_estados.id
INNER JOIN as_campanhas ON as_assinaturas.campanha_id = as_campanhas.id 
INNER JOIN as_produtos ON as_produtos.id = as_campanhas.produto_id 
INNER JOIN as_pagamentos ON as_assinaturas.id = as_pagamentos.id 
INNER JOIN as_ordens ON as_assinaturas.id = as_ordens.assinatura_id
INNER JOIN as_tipo_assinaturas ON as_tipo_assinaturas.id = as_assinaturas.tipo_assinatura_id
INNER JOIN as_representantes ON as_representantes.id = as_assinaturas.representante_id

WHERE as_assinaturas.status = "A"

LIMIT 3
```

Comment: Você precisa antes entender onde está o problema usando alguma ferramenta que possa gerar o plano de execução (query plan) da sua consulta. Pode existir várias causas: algum `id` não indexado, muitas informações retornadas (você não nos informou quantos registros são retornados), quantos registros existem em cada tabela, se o `status` está indexado, etc. São muitas variáveis, sem conhecer as tabelas, índices e quantidade de registros, quantidade de registros retornados, etc... fica difícil ajudar.

Comment: é certo que esses replaces e o like estão atrapalhando, mas sem um exemplo mínimo não conseguiremos fazer nada. Tente montar o ambiente no SQLFiddle